# How do I make files save for concurrent C access?

Tags: c

I have several C-programs, which are accessing (read: fprintf/ write fopen) at the same time different files on the file system. What is the best way to do this concurrent access save? should I write some sort of file locks (and whats the best way to do this?) or are there any better reading methods (preferably in the C99 standard lib, additional dependencies would be a problem)? or should I use something like SQLite?

edit:
I am using Linux as operating system.

edit:
I don't really want to write with different processes in same files, I'm dealing with a legacy monolith code, which saves intermediate steps in files for recycling. I want a way to speed the calculations up by running several calculations at the same time, which have the same intermediate results.

Comment: File locking is not specified in the C standard, so it's OS dependent. In other words, look up the APIs for your OS that detect things like files being modified etc.

Comment: are you sure you want multiple processes writing to the same file ?

Comment: Yes, it might be a better idea to have one process with a write queue to the file and let the other processes send it write requests.

Comment: Some sort of micro service read/write dispatcher as intermediate layer? Do you have a specific example on that?

Comment: @PaulG. Unix Domain Sockets + service which receives results of calculations as socket messages and saves them to file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fcntl()` with `F_SETLK` or `F_SETLKW`:

```
struct flock lock;
...
fcntl( fd, F_SETLKW, &lock );
```

See more from [man page fcntl(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fcntl) or [this](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/flocking.html) article.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that your files do not get corrupted on concurrent writes from multiple threads/processes by using copy-on-the-write technique:

1. A writer opens the file it would like to update for reading.
2. The writer creates a new file with a unique name ([`mkostemps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html)) and copies the original file into the copy.
3. The writer modifies the copy.
4. The writer renames the copy to the original name using [`rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html). This happens atomically, so that users of the file either see the old version of it or the new, but never a partially updated file.

See [Things UNIX can do atomically](http://rcrowley.org/2010/01/06/things-unix-can-do-atomically.html) for more details.